# Return hash with multiple key/value pairs from raw sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm building a ruby on rails application that uses raw SQL to query my database.

Lets say for simplicity’s sake, I have the following records in Table1:

```
<date:"2020-06-09 23:10:00", pid: 1, price: 5, tax: 0.65, shipping: 10>
<date:"2020-06-09 13:00:00", pid: 1, price: 10, tax: 1.3, shipping: 12>
<date:"2020-06-10 10:00:00", pid: 2, price: 20, tax: 2.6, shipping: 11>
<date:"2020-06-10 11:00:00", pid: 3, price: 5, tax: 0.65, shipping: 13>
```

My query is supposed to return a hash where each key represents a day, and the values would be the count of unique `pid` and a summation of the rest of the values. So the response in this case would be:

```
{
   2020-06-09: {
      pid_count: 1,
      price: 15,
      tax: 1.95,
      shipping: 22
   },
   2020-06-10: {
      pid_count: 2,
      price: 25,
      tax: 3.25,
      shipping: 24
   }
}
```

My query is:

```
query = <<-SQL
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(table1.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), COUNT(DISTINCT table1.pid) as pid_count,
  sum(table1.price) as price, sum(table1.tax) as tax, sum(table1.shipping) as shipping from table1
  group by TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(table1.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
SQL
results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).values
```

The calculation is correct but the problem is this doesn't group them properly into a hash. Calling .to_h on `results` gives an error `ArgumentError (wrong array length at 0 (expected 2, was 5))`

Comment: I think you should be grouping by pid and then by date.

Comment: I dont see the `FROM` in your query. Does the `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query).values` success before you call `.to_h`?

Comment: @Thang sorry! i missed it but added it back in the the original post.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't call `to_h` is because the method is expecting the structure:

```
[
  [key, value],
  [key, value],
  # ...
]
```

whereas you have the structure:

```
[
  [value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5],
  [value_1, value_2, value_3, value_4, value_5],
  # ...
]
```

To correctly convert it into the structure you want you have to tell `to_h` how to do so by providing a block.

```
column_names = %i[pid_count price tax shipping]
hash = results.to_h { |date, *values| [date, column_names.zip(values).to_h] }
```

This tells the `to_h` call to use the date as key, then zip the column names with the other values and convert them to a hash and use them as value.

The above might solve the issue, but in most cases there is no need to use `execute` to start with. Assuming `table1` has a model I'd recommend using model methods instead like `group` and `select`/`pluck`. Those can be given SQL or Arel for more complex queries.

Comment: @3lmin4t0r that didn't seem to work but +1 for the explanation and idea

Comment: What does `result` exactly contain? I assumed that it was an array with arrays of length 5, because of the exception you got. Seems my guess was wrong.

Comment: `result` does contain exactly what you think. However, I'm still getting the same error: `ArgumentError (wrong array length at 0 (expected 2, was 5))`

Comment: @jim I tested, its working for ruby version **> 2.6** and clearly you are not using these new versions. The reason is because of the old to_h **only accepts an array with 2 elements**. Just change the last line from 3limin4t0r a bit as below.

`results.map { |date, *values| [date, column_names.zip(values).to_h] }.to_h`